# I look for a way to sort the list I get displayed from the fhir example databases

Tags: java, arraylist, hl7-fhir

I want to sort the list i get from the fhir database. Its basically an array list which requests it, i dont see the Data itself in the java source code

tried to sort it with html with didnt work.
I also tried the sort() method of the Collections class.
Then, reverse array list using the reverse() method.

```java
ArrayList<sample.jersey.db.Patient> list = new ArrayList<sample.jersey.db.Patient>();

        for (Entry e : response.getEntry()) {
            Patient p = (Patient) e.getResource();
            sample.jersey.db.Patient pat = new sample.jersey.db.Patient();
            pat.setId(p.getId().getIdPartAsLong());
            pat.setName(p.getNameFirstRep().getNameAsSingleString());
            try {
                pat.setBirthdate(p.getBirthDate().toString());
            }
            catch (NullPointerException ex){
                pat.setBirthdate("missing");
            }
            list.add(pat);
            patientRepository.save(pat);
            logger.info(p.toString() + ": " + e.getFullUrl());
            logger.info("Name: " + p.getNameFirstRep().getNameAsSingleString());
            //logger.info("Birthdate: " + p.getBirthDate().toString());
        }


        model.addAttribute("p_repo", serverBase);
        model.addAttribute("p_info", infoBase);
        model.addAttribute("p_number", response.getEntry().size());

        model.addAttribute("patientList", list);
        if (response.getTotal() == null)
            model.addAttribute("p_total", "Not Available");
        else
            model.addAttribute("p_total", response.getTotal());
```

```java
        FhirContext ctx = FhirContext.forDstu2();

        String serverBase = "http://hapi.fhir.org/baseDstu2";

        String infoBase = "https://fhirtest.uhn.ca/resource?serverId=hapi_dev&pretty=true&resource=Patient";
        serverId=hapi_dev&pretty=true&resource=Patient
        IGenericClient client = ctx.newRestfulGenericClient(serverBase);


        ca.uhn.fhir.model.dstu2.resource.Bundle response = client.search().forResource(Patient.class)
                // .where(Patient.BIRTHDATE.beforeOrEquals().day("2017-01-01"))
                // .and(Patient.CAREPROVIDER.hasChainedProperty(Organization.NAME.matches().value("Health")))
                .returnBundle(ca.uhn.fhir.model.dstu2.resource.Bundle.class).execute();
```

```java
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Date date;
    private String birthdate;


    public Patient() {
    }

    public Patient(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = new Date();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Patient{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", date=" + date +
                '}';
    }

    public String getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(String birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }
}
```

it basically nothing changed so far when i checked the site again

Comment: Please clarify your question - what code (and version) are you using? what are you trying to do? what does "nothing changed so far when i checked the site again" mean - what did you expect to change?

Comment: Im sorry for being unspecific. I use Java Version 8, i use this spring framework and fhir to connect to the fhir database. I try to sort the datas the html page shows me after i started the application. its just a table with an id, a name, and a birth date and i try to make it possible to sort them descanding and ascending. I hoped that with the collections sort method this would be possible.

Comment: Your code doesn't include anything about Collections.sort() ?

Comment: Yes, i deleted it after it worked, but i as i had the collections code included it looked like this:         ``ArrayList<sample.jersey.db.Patient> list = new ArrayList<sample.jersey.db.Patient>();
  
  Collections.reverse(list);``